# Impersonation of a domain account outside of a domain

Tags: .net, authentication, active-directory, vpn, impersonation

I have a click once application that uses Windows Auth to authenticate against WCF services. However I am trying to allow users to run this application at home via a VPN connection. The main issue here is that the DefaultNetworkCredentials aren't setup correctly.

I was hoping to detect if the user was AD connected by using

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.StartsWith(@"{DOMAIN NAME}\", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

But after that I can't figure out how to impersonate the domain user whilst on a home machine...

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net)?

Comment: tried what? I've so far been pretty unsuccessful in trying to impersonate a user on a non-AD machine.

Comment: The approaches described in the link. You cannot impersonate someone unless you either have his/her UPN and PW or a delegated Kerberos credential. Since this is outside of a domain, Kerberos won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to tackle this at the user level,

C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /netonly /user:\ "YOURAPPPATH"

Try having them run your app like this from the command line.  (Or possibly, with the installation include a shortcut that looks like that)

They'll need to re-enter the domain password each time they run.

Here's more info on runas [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx)